# Pointing socket.io client to heroku service

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, socket.io

I have used socket.io, Node.JS, and express to create a real-time chat application that I could view by creating a local server. However, instead of using a local server, I would like to point my client to an existent heroku service. How do I go about doing this?

When I do the following,

```
var spot = io("https://spotim-demo-chat-server.herokuapp.com");
```

all functions relating to connecting, disconnecting, username registration, and messaging seem to fail. They do not function in the chat nor do their console.log messages appear in terminal.

I have also considered creating a HTTP server and having it listen to the port and IP address of the heroku service with .listen(). However for my assignment, I was not provided with either of these values, simply the heroku url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're having trouble without more code from you. I've setup a basic socket.io client as follows and can connect without issue. You can run it with the following to see just the client's messages `DEBUG=spot-client node client.js` or if you wish to see all the debug info from the socket client itself as well `DEBUG=* node client.js`. The latter might help you diagnose the issue further. Also be sure to install the `socket.io-client` and `debug` packages. Hope this helps!

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const debug = require('debug')('spot-client');
var spot = io("https://spotim-demo-chat-server.herokuapp.com");

spot.on('connect', function(){
    debug("connected");
});
spot.on('event', function(data){
    debug("event",data);
});
spot.on('disconnect', function(){
    debug("disconnect");
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I think it's working now. The debug information was especially heplful!

Comment: @Dylbert I'm glad this helped. Please do accept the answer if it solved your problem, if not, happy to help further.